# HttpClient + gzip at PCL causes method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.ser_AutomaticDecompression'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, gzip, httpclient, portable-class-library

I'm adding gzip compression support to an Xamarin.Android app where HttpClient reside in Portable Class Library (Profile49).

Every time I'm trying to make a HttpClient call I'm getting the following error:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.ser_AutomaticDecompression

the code is the following:

```
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
 handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
 using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
 ...
```

Comment: what version of xamarin are you using? same with studio?

Comment: the latest from alpha channel: 1. Xamarin.Android (VS Plugin) 4.16.0.14 | 2. Xamarin.Studio 5.4 (build 236) | 3. Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 | 4. API Level 19+

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue using a stable build? Aka non-alpha?

Comment: @AlexeyStrakh Did you solved this problem? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken you'll need to add a reference to the httpclient package in the project you consume your PCL in. A reference within your PCL is not going to be enough, your other projects need to reference the httpclient BCL nuget package as well.

Comment: Adding 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14' to CFSA.Android.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jj95xh44tb1ksja/shot_140916_143132.png?dl=0